# Making a p2p UDP sharing folder java

Tags: java, file, udp, p2p, sharing

I'm making a p2p file transfer but I don't know how to share my list of file inside folder that I want to share to another client [1 folder is 1 client shared folder for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcmgB.png)

I was try to send it with UDP inside a list, but I think it have better way to send. And how to download a file in shared list.